# All functions of the p5.js library aren't working for some reason

Tags: javascript, neural-network, console

I'm trying to apply a sort of mesh onto the the webcam video using JavaScript. In addition, I do also want to use the methods of the P5.js library to save a canvas image. The code that I am using is from: https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Face-Detection-JavaScript
I just wanted to play around with it.
When I initially ran the guy's code, it work's great but, like I said, I wanted to also use the P5.js library so this was my index.html to get the library.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
  <script defer src="face-api.min.js"></script>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    canvas {
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="video" width="720" height="560" autoplay muted></video>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code in the editor, it says that whatever method I'm using like(saveCanvas()) is not defined. The only reason why I wanted to use the P5 library was to use this method because I need the facemesh image.
Does anyone know the reason why the code is wrong thanks!

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]

Comment: Since this is a javascript problem, you should include `script.js` in your question.

Comment: Check your browser's console, the developers of `p5.js` were smart enough to guess what errors people might run into. In mine it says `Did you just try to use p5.js's saveCanvas() function? If so, you may want to move it into your sketch's setup() function.`

Comment: @Countour-Integral in the console, it says that the method like saveCanvas() is not defined in the scope.

Answer (score 1):

P5 sometimes acts weird if you leave out parts of the tag in my experience. Try this instead:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-WIklPM6qPCIp6d3fSSr90j+1unQHUOoWDS4sdTiR8gxUTnyZ8S2Mr8e10sKKJ/bhJgpAa/qG068RDkg6fIlNFA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You also didn't specify where you are putting your P5 code. If you're

1. embedding it directly into the body of your HTML, make sure you've remembered the script tags
2. adding it to script.js or face-api.min.js - I don't know the content of those scripts, but try removing the defer so that the P5 library fully loads before any DOM events occur. If that doesn't work, move them inside the body tags (still leave out defer) and leave the p5 library in the head.